# How to press an <a> link with zombie.js?

Tags: bdd, zombie.js, cucumberjs

I am using behavior driven development with cucumber-js, and trying to write a test to follow a link, and I have the following code:

```
When I click "Add page"

this.When(/^I click "([^"]*)"$/, function(link, callback) {
  this.browser.pressButton(link, callback);
});
```

Add page is a link button:

```
<a href="/surveys"><button>Add page</button></a>
```

The idea that the zombie rest on the same page after pressing the button, is there an other way ?

Comment: pressButton requires a special type of element (button element or input of type 'submit'). In this case maybe the click is received by <a> element and in this case you should use click method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function pressButton is used to press a button the page.
For clicking a link on a page use clickLink function.

So your code should be:

`this.When(/^I click "([^"]*)"$/, function(link, callback) {
    this.browser.clickLink(link, callback);
});`